# WPF - Binding inside usercontrol content

Tags: wpf

I'm new in WPF and I have problems encountered. Why the binding of ListView ItemSource inside the sectionControls:ViewDefaultLayout element is not working. But when I try to remove the ListView element outside of the  sectionControls:ViewDefaultLayout element the categories are showing.

CategoriesControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="POS.Wpf.Controls.CategoriesControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POS.Wpf.Controls"
         xmlns:sectionControls="clr-namespace:POS.Wpf.Controls.Section"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
         x:Name="categoryUserControl">
<Grid>
    <sectionControls:ViewDefaultLayout Title="Categories" Add="ViewDefaultLayout_Add" Delete="ViewDefaultLayout_Delete">
        <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Categories}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </sectionControls:ViewDefaultLayout>
</Grid>
```

ViewDefaultLayout.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="POS.Wpf.Controls.Section.ViewDefaultLayout"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POS.Wpf.Controls.Section"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
        <DockPanel>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Label Content="{Binding Title}" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource BoldLargeLabel}"></Label>
            </Grid>
            <Border Padding="10">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0 0 0 5">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="135" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBox Text="Search" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#FFE4DFDF" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"></TextBox>
                                <Button x:Name="SearchButton" Padding="5" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="SearchButton_Click">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="#A2A6AC" Kind="Search" Width="30" Height="30"  />
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <Button x:Name="AddButton" Padding="5" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 5 0" Click="AddButton_Click">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="#A2A6AC" Kind="Add" Width="50" Height="30"  />
                                </Button>
                                <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Padding="5" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="DeleteButton_Click">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="#A2A6AC" Kind="Delete" Width="50" Height="30"  />
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </DockPanel>

            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Comment: The expression `{Binding DataContext.Categories}` doesn't seem to make sense. It assumes that there is an object in the current DataContext that has itself a DataContext property.

Comment: Hi @Clemens, the Categories is property on my viewmodel. It's working when I remove it outside the sectionControls:ViewDefaultLayout user control. The problem is when I put it inside the usercontrol.

Comment: If it's a view model property, the binding expression should be `{Binding Categories}`. And you must not explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext (in case you did that, which we don't know).

Comment: Yes I already did that and it also works outside the usercontrol content. How to use binding inside the usercontrol content?